# How to avoid Division in Sql returning 0 or NULL

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a score of product sold at Full Price vs Markdown using GCP.

I wrote:

```
(Sum(if(t1.Markdown_Flag=1, t1.Value__GBP_,0)) / Sum(if(t1.Markdown_Flag=0,t1.Value__GBP_,0))*100) as Percentage_MD
```

However I have an issue as both of the sum can be = 0.

The error message is:

```
division by zero: 88 / 0
```

Thanks

Comment: So in the case of `88/0`, what would you want as a result? 88? 0? Null? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this formula.

```
(Sum(if(t1.Markdown_Flag=1, t1.Value__GBP_,0)) / if(Sum(if(t1.Markdown_Flag=0,t1.Value__GBP_,0))*100)=0,1,Sum(if(t1.Markdown_Flag=0,t1.Value__GBP_,0))*100)) as Percentage_MD
```

To break this down, I added another another `if` condition just outside the denominator to handle the case if the result of `sum` equals 0, then use 1 (so that the error is not received), otherwise use the sum.

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
(Sum(case when t1.Markdown_Flag=1 then t1.Value__GBP_ else 0end) * 100.0 /
 Sum(case when t1.Markdown_Flag = 0 then t1.Value__GBP_ end) 
) as Percentage_MD
```

Note that this uses the standard `case` expression syntax (rather than a bespoke `if()` function).  It multiplies by 100.0 for a percentage -- just in case your database uses integer devision.

Leaving off the `else` clause in the denominator solves the division by zero problem -- assuming the values are never `0`.  If the can be, then use:

```
(sum(case when t1.Markdown_Flag=1 then t1.Value__GBP_ else 0end) * 100.0 /
 nullif(um(case when t1.Markdown_Flag = 0 then t1.Value__GBP_ end), 0)
) as Percentage_MD
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon for your help! the second formula solved my issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the divisor *can* be 0 then you need to decide how to represent or handle that infinite/undefined value.

Options are an approximation of infinity (ie a very large number as a proxy) or possibly 0 or 1 or whatever makes sense to the rest of your code. Or even throw an exception if this is *not* an acceptable outcome (even if it's possible).

Your code can only do so much; you have to "tell" it how to manage outlier results.

(In this instance, if a 0 divisor is valid, I'd probably conditionally set the result to a known large number that otherwise would not occur, say, 999999999 or 987654321 or something that I can identify as the result as emanating from this situation.)

PS You should ad some tags to your question.